# How to configure Angular/nginx routing with proper status codes

Tags: angular, nginx, url, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm struggling to find any good documentation or guides on how to setup the routing in Angular and Nginx to support the following logic:

```
Route                            File       Status

example.com                   -> index.html 200 OK
example.com/path              -> index.html 200 OK
example.com/not-found         -> index.html 404 NOT FOUND
example.com/another-not-found -> index.html 404 NOT FOUND
```

Important points:

- Refreshing the page should give the same result
- Going to a path that doesn't exist should not redirect, it should give a 404 status code and show the 404 page.

Is there a way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible to make Angular work this way. Using the Angular docs as an example, they don't do it either.

Even though Google themselves says this is a bad practice: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/soft-404-errors

Fortunately it's not a massive issue as Google does try to recognize pages with a 200 status as a 404 as long as the content on the page makes it clear enough that it's actually a 404.

One SEO improvment can be seen in the Angular docs source code:

```js
// Dynamically, pre-emptively, add `noindex`, which will be removed when the doc is ready and valid
const tag = document.createElement('meta');
tag.name = 'robots';
tag.content = 'noindex';
document.head.appendChild(tag);
```

This will add `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` to all pages. They then remove this tag once they know the page is valid (ie. not 404).